# Async doInBackground not Getting Called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In below class the using async inner class function doInBackground is not getting Hit.   while calling rpi.excute and then trying to get the data through getQuestionnaireBO  downloaded by HTTP , I have the Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml and other  config    to

```
public class RestApiClient {
    private final static String SERVICE_URI = "http://182.50.154.23/Dattab.Device.Rest/ServiceClass/RestDeviceService.svc";
    private QuestionnaireBO resultQuestionnaireBO ;
    public void Questionnairedownload(int QuestionnaireId ) {
        String url=SERVICE_URI+"/DownloadQuestionnaireData/"+QuestionnaireId;
        // InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);
        // Gson gson = new Gson();
        // Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
        // QuestionnaireBO response = gson.fromJson(reader, QuestionnaireBO.class);
        ChildThreadQuestionnairedownload ctqd = new ChildThreadQuestionnairedownload();
        ctqd.execute(url);

        // return null ;        
    }

    public QuestionnaireBO getQuestionnaireBO() {
        return resultQuestionnaireBO;
    }


    private class ChildThreadQuestionnairedownload extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,QuestionnaireBO> {

        @Override
        protected QuestionnaireBO doInBackground(String... params) {
             String url=params[0];
             Gson gson = new Gson();
             DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();                     
             HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
             try {
                 HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
                 final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                 if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                      Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                            "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
                      return null;
                 }

                 HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
                 Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(getResponseEntity.getContent());
                 QuestionnaireBO response = gson.fromJson(reader, QuestionnaireBO.class);

                  return response ;
             }
             catch(IOException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  return null;
             }

         }

         protected void onPostExecute(QuestionnaireBO response) {
             resultQuestionnaireBO=response;
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: where you are calling this method Questionnairedownload(123);

Comment: And how did you realize that `doInBackground()` method is not getting called?

Comment: Did you try to debug (with breakpoints) ?

Comment: Any reason you are using an AsyncTask outside of a UI? Perhaps all you need is a good old fashioned Thread?

Comment: @PadmaKumar I am calling it from other class like RestApiClient client=new RestApiClient();         client.Questionnairedownload(obj.QuestionnaireId);
QuestionnaireBO data=client.getQuestionnaireBO();

Comment: @trgraglia Error : threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception after then NULL Pointer exception clearly because the return value is null

Comment: @KumarVishal, do you have a line number or any additional info on the null exception?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why `doInBackground()` won't get called.

This probably is a dump one, but... did you make sure you have the internet connection up?
Sometimes, if you are on a wi-fi the connection may be lost, and if you are using 3G it may be that you spent all your money. So, no access to internet.