# doInBackground() is not working when using Async with JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am trying to fetch some data from my database (MySQL) hosted on a server.
And for that, I am using JDBC with Async. I have used the same code in another app. And it worked fine. But when I am trying to do the same thing in this app. doInBackGround() method is not being called.

I have used the connection class as an inner class. And Initialized an array named last. I have changed its 0th index to some random string and printed that in the postExecute(). But it was null and that how I came to know that doInBackground() is never called. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
    public class connection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        Context context;
        String[] last = new String[5];


        connection(Context ctx) {
            context = ctx;

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            last[0] = "something";
//            try {
//                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
//
//                if (con == null) {
//                        last[0]= "con issue";
//                } else {
//                    String Query = "select * from users where ID like '" + search + "';";
//                    last[0] = "in else";
//                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
//                    last[0] = "after stm";
//                    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
//                    last[0] = "after execute";
//                    while (res.next()) {
//                        last[0] = "insidewhile";
////                        last[0] =  res.getString("NAME");
////                        last[1] = res.getString("KISAM");
////                        last[2] = res.getString("MOKA");
////                        last[3] = res.getString("ONWAN");
////
//                        return null;
//                    }
//
//                    last[0] = "not";
//                }
//                con.close();
//            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
//                last[0] = e.getException().getMessage();
//                Log.e("ClassNotFoundException", e.getException().getMessage());
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            } catch (SQLException e) {
//                last[0] = e.toString();
//                Log.e("SQL ERROR",e.toString());
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Searching", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            String S = last[0];
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(S) || s == null){
                Toast.makeText(context, " doinBackground() not called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(Search.this, "S", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                if (!S.contentEquals("not")) {
//                    kisa = (last[1]);
//                    mok = (last[2]);
//                    Name = (last[0]);
//                    onwa = (last[3]);
//                    AF.setText(Name);
//                    AF.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                } else {
//
//                    Toast.makeText(Search.this, "NO Record Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        }

    }
```

There is no error in the logcat. Even I loged in catch blocks.

Comment: Questions Like below didn't help me at all.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856322/doinbackground-in-async-task-not-working-properly

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841303/async-doinbackground-not-getting-called

Answer (score 0):

Android newbie here. I think that it would be best if you made a PHP script that will do all this work, and call it via HttpURLConnection.

Also you should use PreparedStatements instead of Statements to avoid SQL injections.